# Spotify Login URL rejected by .canHandle method

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, spotify

I tried following the Spotify ioS SDK Tutorial (https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/tutorial/). After a login URL is constructed using the SPTAuth methods below, the tutorial says to check if the login URL is a valid Spotify Authorization URL using: `SPTAuth.defaultInstance().canHandleURL(loginURL)`. However, this method returns false, preventing me from logging the user in.

Here is the code that sets my login URL:

```
    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().clientID = "3d9c120475a047fab9b1d735ca68dce8"
    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().redirectURL = NSURL(string: "second-test-spotify://callback")
    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().requestedScopes = [SPTAuthStreamingScope]
    var loginURL = SPTAuth.defaultInstance().loginURL
```

I also tried this alternate class method to set the login URL, which also did not work.

```
let loginURL = SPTAuth.loginURLForClientId("3d9c120475a047fab9b1d735ca68dce8", withRedirectURL: NSURL(string: "second-test-spotify://callback"), scopes: [SPTAuthStreamingScope], responseType: "token")
```

And here is the login URL returned by both of these methods:

```
spotify-action://authorize?client_id=3d9c120475a047fab9b1d735ca68dce8&scope=streaming&redirect_uri=second-test-spotify%3A%2F%2Fcallback&nosignup=true&nolinks=false&response_type=token
```

My code is in Swift even though the Spotify SDK is in Objective C since I used a bridging header.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was calling the openURL function, which contains the .canHandle method, incorrectly. I moved my code to the AppDelegate.swift file and replaced the openURL function definition with this function definition:

`func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {`

Then I called application.openURL after creating the loginURL, and it works correctly.